# How to normalize data between -1 and 1?

Tags: dataset, normalization

I have seen the min-max normalization formula but that normalizes values between 0 and 1. How would I normalize my data between -1 and 1? I have both negative and positive values in my data matrix.

Comment: If you're working in R, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468280/scale-a-series-between-two-points-in-r) for a few options. In particular, a comment on the accepted answer has this function where you set the 'newMax' to 1 and 'newMin' to -1 and run the function on your data

Comment: You can find reference at Wikipedia as follows:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)

Comment: Javascript example, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224535/scaling-between-two-number-ranges). function convertRange( value, r1, r2 ) { return ( value - r1[ 0 ] ) * ( r2[ 1 ] - r2[ 0 ] ) / ( r1[ 1 ] - r1[ 0 ] ) + r2[ 0 ]; } convertRange( 328.17, [ 300.77, 559.22 ], [ 1, 10 ] ); >>> 1.9541497388276272

Comment: @covfefe if you are still around you might want to accept one of the answers

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/25902234d9422f5d70ec2db3a5619f68) is a Python gist of the Javascript command `convertRange` shared by Giuseppe Canale.

Answer (score 195):

With:
$$
x' = \frac{x - \min{x}}{\max{x} - \min{x}}
$$
you normalize your feature $x$ in $[0,1]$.

To normalize in $[-1,1]$ you can use:

$$
x'' = 2\frac{x - \min{x}}{\max{x} - \min{x}} - 1
$$

In general, you can always get a new variable $x'''$ in $[a,b]$:

$$
x''' = (b-a)\frac{x - \min{x}}{\max{x} - \min{x}} + a
$$

And in case you want to bring a variable back to its original value you can do it because these are **linear transformations** and thus **invertible**. For example:

$$
x = (x''' - a)\frac{(\max{x} - \min{x})}{b-a} + \min{x}
$$

An example in Python:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 3, 4, 5, -1, -7])
# goal : range [0, 1]
x1 = (x - min(x)) / ( max(x) - min(x) )
print(x1)
>>> [0.66666667 0.83333333 0.91666667 1. 0.5 0.]
```

Comment: Honestly I don't have citations for this. It is just a linear transformation of a random variable. Have a look at the effect of linear transformations on the support of a random variable.

Comment: Do you have better methods to do this?

Comment: @GoingMyWay better from what point of view?

Comment: Appreciate the final general formula for any interval $[a,b]$

Comment: @Simone: Is there a way to renormalize all the values? i.e. bring them back to their original values?

Comment: @ThePredator this is a linear transformation of a random variable, so it is invertible. But you need to know the original $\max{x}$ and $\min{x}$. If you have $x''$ (as in the formula above) in $[-1,1]$ you can get back to $x$ with $(\max{x} - \min{x})\frac{x''+1}{2} + \min{x}$.

Comment: or in general: $x=\frac{(x'''-a)(\max{x}-\min{x})}{b-a}+\min{x}$. I advise keeping your original and normalised datasets, you can then find $\max{x}$ and $\min{x}$ easily by just looking at your original dataset again.

Comment: Just a remark: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html performs the same normalization as in $x'''$

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/1689ed908f7bca0dea9a52c5eda1bff7) is a Python gist of $x^{\prime\prime\prime}$.

Answer (score -3):

I tested on randomly generated data, and

\begin{equation}
    X_{out} = (b-a)\frac{X_{in} - \min{X_{in}}}{\max{X_{in}} - \min{X_{in}}} + a
\end{equation}

does not preserve the shape of the distribution. Would really like to see the proper derivation of this using functions of random variables.

The approach that did preserve the shape for me was using:

\begin{equation}
    X_{out} = \frac{X_{in} - \mu_{in}}{\sigma_{in}} \cdot \sigma_{out} + \mu_{out}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
    \sigma_{out} = \frac{b-a}{6}
\end{equation}

(I admit that using 6 is a bit *dirty*) and

\begin{equation}
    \mu_{out} = \frac{b+a}{2}
\end{equation}

and

$a$ and $b$ is the desired range; so as per original question would be $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

I arrived at the result from this reasoning

\begin{equation}
    Z_{out} = Z_{in}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{X_{out} - \mu_{out}}{\sigma_{out}} = \frac{X_{in} - \mu_{in}}{\sigma_{in}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you sure that this guarantees the transformed data will lie within the bounds?  In R, try: `set.seed(1); scale(rnorm(1000))*.333`.  I get a max of `1.230871`. Your method seems to be just a tweak on standardizing data, rather than normalizing them as requested. Note that the question does not ask for a method that preserves the shape of the distribution (which would be a strange requirement for normalization).

Comment: I'm not sure how the original transformation could fail to preserve the shape of the data. It's equivalent to subtracting a constant and then dividing by a constant, which is what your proposal does, and which doesn't change the shape of the data. Your proposal assumes all the data falls within three standard deviations of the mean, which may be somewhat reasonable with small, approximately normally distributed samples, but not with big or non-normal samples.

Comment: @Noah It's not equivalent to subtracting and dividing by *constants,* because the min and max of the data are *random variables.*  Indeed, for most underlying distributions they are pretty variable--more variable than the rest of the data--whence using them for any form of standardization is usually not a good idea.  In this answer it's unclear what $a$ and $b$ mean or how they might be related to the data.

Comment: @whuber true, but I meant that in a given dataset (i.e., treating the data as fixed), they are constants, in the same way the sample mean and sample standard deviation function as constants when standardizing a dataset. My impression was that OP wanted to normalize a dataset, not a distribution.

Comment: @Noah I had the same impression, but I believe the present post may be responding to a different interpretation.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/e8d8776e9807d7950937887933c38984) is a Python gist of A.L. Verminburger's scaling approach.